# Python: Most Efficient method of printing strings and numbers

Tags: python, performance, printing

In Python, which would be the most efficient way to print a string and an integer in the same call of print()

```
print("String" +str(3))
```

or

```
print("string",5)
```

Thanks

Comment: print("string5") would be most efficient.

Comment: On my system, the first way with `str()` saves 10 nanoseconds!  Out of 500 total, so it's pointless.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps:

```
print ("string %d" % (42))
```

or any of a dozen other different ways?

If you *really* want to know comparative performance, you *measure* it, and measure it in the target environment. That's the way to be certain.

But, and this is important, unless you actually *have* a performance issue in printing out strings with numbers possible, I'll admit, but unlikely), your effort is totally wasted.

The amount of time you will save with this will be small enough that you're almost certainly better off investing your optimisation effort elsewhere, such as with more judicious selection of algorithms and data structures.